# О слове "травить"

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Если брать украинский язык, который, как мне кажется, сохранил больше славянских корней, то слово "травлення" - это "переваривание". То есть, как я понимаю, изначально корень "трав-" говорил о принадлежности к пищеварению. По той же логике можно предположить, что слово "отрава" означает нечто ядовитое, что съедено. Но как тогда объяснить слова, не относящиеся к пищеварению даже отдаленно: "стравливать" (кого-то с кем-то), "травить" в значении "охотиться"  и "травить" в значении "выпускать воздух"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ТРАВИТЬ** «истреблять, поедать на корню» (посевы), «умерщвлять 
отравой», «вызывать раздражение едким веществом». Древн. слав. слово. 
Развилось из праслав. *trovQ,* truti «тереть, перетирать», «съедать, по- 
треблять» в результате удлинения **о** и изменения его в **а**.
Праслав. глаг. *traviti > травити «перетирать, съедать», «истреблять» 
(ср. стар. воен.* травитися, стравитися с неприятелем *«завязать бой») дал 
производные с приставками:* потравить *«истребить траву, посевы», «отравить многих», а от него с пом. темы -а—:* потрава *«истребление, порча травы, посевов»;* отравить *«дать яда», от него с пом. темы -а — сущ.* отрава* «яд», устар. «отравление».

Comment: Сразу возникает вопрос: однокоренные ли слова "травить" и "трава"?

Comment: Однокоренные. Поскольку это не вопрос, а комментарий, отсылаю к источникам. См. Этимологический словарь Цыганенко, а также Фасмер, на которого вы ссылаетесь.

Answer (score 0):

А Вы смотрели в интернете? Я там нашла смысл "переваривать", откуда уже недалеко до смыслов, связанных с уничтожением или повреждением чего-то.

Comment: Просьба: в ответах не надо ссылаться на интернет. Если все будут смотреть в интернете, отпадет надобность в этом ресурсе. Если поставлен вопрос, то нужно давать на него ответ.  
С уважением,  
администратор

Comment: обственно, это был Фасмер, только опубликованный в интернете.